# nodejs: string manipulation

Tags: node.js, substring

I have the following node.js code:

```
   conn.on("data",function(x){
       var responseData=x;
       //sys.puts(responseData);
       sys.puts(responseData.length);

       var f=50;
       var N=responseData.length;
       if(N>f){
         var p=Math.floor(N/f);
         var p_rem=N%f;

         var hash="";
         for(var i=0;i<p;i++){
           hash=DJBHash(responseData.substr(f*i,f));   //this line causes program to exit!
           sys.puts(responseData.substr(f*i,f)+"***"+hash);
         }
       }
       soc.write(x);
    });
```

But substr doesn't appear to work!

How can I get substrings of a string in node.js?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: its probablye `DJBHash` that fails

Comment: I commented out that line... The next line is failing now...

Comment: try `Object.prototype.toString.call(responseData)`

Comment: Hi, I tried `responseData=Object.prototype.toString.call(responseData)`, but it didn't work...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The variable data is of type Buffer, you would have to create a string with the method toString and then, you will be able to do the substr. Something like that will work :

```
responseData.toString().substr(1)
```

For more info consult this link :

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/buffers.html#buffer.toString

Comment: Hi, that worked really well. I was wondering do you know how to go from a string back to the type that "responseData" is?

Comment: According to the documentation : `new Buffer(myStr)` will do it http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/buffers.html#new_Buffer

Comment: I should advise you to read quickly the manual to see more or less what every module is doing that should give you a good overview of the possibilities you have.