# Check for 'http://' text in json object with Chai.js Should

Tags: node.js, chai

I've got some nested objects inside each object and I want to check with chai that the images's hrefs start with 'http://'

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "header": {
                "href": "http://somedomain.com/assets/header.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "logo": {
                "href": "http://somedomain.com/assets/logo.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is, I can't just key off of the image name property because it changes...so I can't do this:

```
images[0].[image name changes!! it's not a concrete property  name].href.should.have.deep.property("href");
```

because imagename is like 'header', 'logo', and so on

so how would I be able to do this with chai and check the href for each image to make sure it's got the text 'http://'?

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically iterate through all objects in the `images` array as @gfpacheco suggested in his answer.

But I would research a way to create a deterministic test.  This would simplify your assertions, but might require some creativity or refactoring to mock or render fixtures

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write the entire Chai assertion function. It uses the [Chai Things](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-things) plugin to work with assertions over arrays:

```
var data = {...};

function startsWithHttp(string) {
  return string.indexOf('http://') === 0;
}

data.images.should.all.satisfy(function(image) {
  Object.keys(image).should.contain.an.item.that.satisfy(function(key) {
    image[key].should.have.all.keys('href');
    image[key].href.should.satisfy(startsWithHttp);
  });
});
```

It assumes that all images should have at least one property that it's value must have an `href` property and it's value starts with `http://`.

Comment: the image name is not always imgName.  So how can I specify a specific image...I mean there is no field called imgName, it's literally the name of the image such as header.jpg, picture that in place of imageName1, etc. that's how the real data is

Comment: Did you try my answer? It doesn't use a fixed name for the property, istead it iterate over all properties (in your case is either "header"or "logo"). I'll update the answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

As I said @dm03514, it's hard to find a deterministic method. I get the sub string of `href` and would verify if is equals (and iterate how @gfpacheco did do). I tried let the same environment for their:

```
var http = "http://";
if(header.href.substr(0,7) === http)
    alert("Header ok"); 
else
    alert("Header no ok")
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/zhrfLa8m/2/

Obs: This is pure javascript, but you can get the substring in node too. [nodejs: string manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081485/nodejs-string-manipulation)